# PineScript Ограничение видимости plot определенным таймфреймом

Tags: pinescript

Я хочу чтобы **некоторые** plot, вызываемые моим индикатором, были видны только на M1 и M5 (1 минута, 5 минут). Можно ли это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так.

```
tf1 = timeframe.period // возвращает текущий ТФ графика
    
vma = ta.vwma(close, 10)

plotting = timeframe.isintraday and tf1=="5" or tf1=="1" ? vma : na // проверка условия совпадения текущего ТФ с заданным

plot(plotting)
```

Comment: Сергей, я только начал изучать Pine, но опыт есть - mql, php. Пока еще не до конца въехал в концепцию языка. Большое Вам спасибо! Выручаете второй раз :)

Comment: Я и сам не эксперт, скажем так :D